# Search Function not searching correct custom_post_type even though post_type is defined in search args

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, search

I have a custom post type of `job_listing` and a custom_post_type of `job_application`.

Each `job_application` post has a parent within the `job_listing` post_type

So if a job listing for an Office Receptionist has 5 applications, then this post will have 5 children within the `job_application` post_type all having their post_parent ID as the Office Receptionist post in the `job_listing` CPT (hope this makes sense?)

Now here's the issue...

A job listing could quite easily have a couple of hundred applications (child posts in the `job_application` CPT) and we need to be able to search for an applicants name within these applications

There are a couple of routes I could take - such as using WP search or WP_Query (I'm using WP_Query here but both methods seem to be facing the same issue...)

The following works as expected, and returns all the Job Applications for the Job Listing with a post ID of 34806

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'job_application',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => 34806,
  );

  $apps = new WP_Query($args);
```

The Query Objects begins as so (this is relevant in little bit...)

```
WP_Query Object
(
  [query] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => job_application
        [post_status] => publish
        [post_parent] => 34806
    )

  [query_vars] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => job_application
        [post_status] => publish
        [post_parent] => 34806
        ...
```

Now here's the issue - Let's say 'Richard' calls to see how his job application is going, and I need to search within my applications for all applicants with the name of Richard (applicant names are all as `the_title` in the CPT)

If I try to search like this it fails to recognise any post with the term `Richard` in the title...

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'job_application',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => 34806,
    's'           => 'Richard'
  );

  $apps = new WP_Query($args);
```

After banging my head against my desk for a couple of days now, I have noticed the WP_Query Object's query_vars (`print_r($apps->query_vars);`) is behaving differently now I have added the `'s' => 'keyword'` parameter to the `$args`...

```
WP_Query Object
(
  [query] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => job_application
        [post_status] => publish
        [post_parent] => 34806
        [s] => Richard
    )

  [query_vars] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => Array
            (
                [0] => job_listing
            )

        [post_status] => publish
        [post_parent] => 34806
        [s] => Richard
        ...
```

By adding the `s` parameter, we have gone from

```
[post_type] => job_application
```

to

```
[post_type] => Array (
  [0] => job_listing
)
```

So I'm guessing this is where the issue is lurking - I have searched high and low but this parent / child relationship between two separate post types seems to be an edge-case I desperately need your help on.

(FYI - I thought the issue was somewhere in the CPT set up - this does not appear to be the case but in both cases the post types share the following settings)

```
'public'              =>  true,
'exclude_from_search' =>  false,
'publicly_queryable'  =>  true,
'capability_type'     =>  'post',
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance and for taking the time to read this.

---

Furthers to Tom's comment

```
WP_Query Object
(
[query] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => job_application
        [post_status] => publish
        [posts_per_page] => 20
        [post_parent] => 34806
        [s] => Richard
        [fields] => ids
    )

[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => Array
            (
                [0] => job_listing
            )

        [post_status] => publish
        [posts_per_page] => 20
        [post_parent] => 34806
        [s] => Richard
        [fields] => ids
        [error] => 
        [m] => 
        [p] => 0
        [subpost] => 
        [subpost_id] => 
        [attachment] => 
        [attachment_id] => 0
        [name] => 
        [pagename] => 
        [page_id] => 0
        [second] => 
        [minute] => 
        [hour] => 
        [day] => 0
        [monthnum] => 0
        [year] => 0
        [w] => 0
        [category_name] => 
        [tag] => 
        [cat] => 
        [tag_id] => 
        [author] => 
        [author_name] => 
        [feed] => 
        [tb] => 
        [paged] => 0
        [meta_key] => 
        [meta_value] => 
        [preview] => 
        [sentence] => 
        [title] => 
        [menu_order] => 
        [embed] => 
        [category__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [category__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [category__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [post__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_name__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag_slug__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag_slug__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_parent__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_parent__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [author__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [author__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [facetwp] => 1
        [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
        [suppress_filters] => 
        [cache_results] => 1
        [update_post_term_cache] => 1
        [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
        [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
        [nopaging] => 
        [comments_per_page] => 50
        [no_found_rows] => 
        [search_terms_count] => 1
        [search_terms] => Array
            (
                [0] => Richard
            )

        [search_orderby_title] => Array
            (
                [0] => wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{996078ef2200d94f9cdfbf332158abaebd24e09e889535b5c4c22d13e69bb91f}Richard{996078ef2200d94f9cdfbf332158abaebd24e09e889535b5c4c22d13e69bb91f}'
            )

        [order] => DESC
    )

[tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
    (
        [queries] => Array
            (
            )

        [relation] => AND
        [table_aliases:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [queried_terms] => Array
            (
            )

        [primary_table] => wp_posts
        [primary_id_column] => ID
    )

[meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
    (
        [queries] => Array
            (
            )

        [relation] => 
        [meta_table] => 
        [meta_id_column] => 
        [primary_table] => 
        [primary_id_column] => 
        [table_aliases:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [clauses:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [has_or_relation:protected] => 
    )

[date_query] => 
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta espm ON (wp_posts.ID = espm.post_id)  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_parent = 34806  AND ( ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{996078ef2200d94f9cdfbf332158abaebd24e09e889535b5c4c22d13e69bb91f}Richard{996078ef2200d94f9cdfbf332158abaebd24e09e889535b5c4c22d13e69bb91f}') OR  (espm.meta_key = 'cvl_job_ref' AND espm.meta_value LIKE '{996078ef2200d94f9cdfbf332158abaebd24e09e889535b5c4c22d13e69bb91f}Richard{996078ef2200d94f9cdfbf332158abaebd24e09e889535b5c4c22d13e69bb91f}')))  AND (wp_posts.post_password = '')  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'job_listing' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{996078ef2200d94f9cdfbf332158abaebd24e09e889535b5c4c22d13e69bb91f}Richard{996078ef2200d94f9cdfbf332158abaebd24e09e889535b5c4c22d13e69bb91f}' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
[posts] => Array
    (
    )

[post_count] => 0
[current_post] => -1
[in_the_loop] => 
[comment_count] => 0
[current_comment] => -1
[found_posts] => 0
[max_num_pages] => 0
[max_num_comment_pages] => 0
[is_single] => 
[is_preview] => 
[is_page] => 
[is_archive] => 1
[is_date] => 
[is_year] => 
[is_month] => 
[is_day] => 
[is_time] => 
[is_author] => 
[is_category] => 
[is_tag] => 
[is_tax] => 
[is_search] => 1
[is_feed] => 
[is_comment_feed] => 
[is_trackback] => 
[is_home] => 
[is_privacy_policy] => 
[is_404] => 
[is_embed] => 
[is_paged] => 
[is_admin] => 
[is_attachment] => 
[is_singular] => 
[is_robots] => 
[is_posts_page] => 
[is_post_type_archive] => 1
[query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => 547db0b03a72d39d0cdfdaa561e2a4a4
[query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 1
[thumbnails_cached] => 
[stopwords:WP_Query:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => about
        [1] => an
        [2] => are
        [3] => as
        [4] => at
        [5] => be
        [6] => by
        [7] => com
        [8] => for
        [9] => from
        [10] => how
        [11] => in
        [12] => is
        [13] => it
        [14] => of
        [15] => on
        [16] => or
        [17] => that
        [18] => the
        [19] => this
        [20] => to
        [21] => was
        [22] => what
        [23] => when
        [24] => where
        [25] => who
        [26] => will
        [27] => with
        [28] => www
    )

[compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => query_vars_hash
        [1] => query_vars_changed
    )

[compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => init_query_flags
        [1] => parse_tax_query
    )

)
```

Comment: What's the actual title of the post you're expecting to see? Note that fetching just the `ids` doesn't do that much for performance here, especially if you're calling `get_post` or any function that retrieves titles meta post content etc, in that situation you'll be forcing WP to make additional queries rather than relying on `WP_Cache` and the built-in "Here's something I prepared earlier" blue peter style caching of post objects in the same request

Comment: Thanks fir the reply Tom - IDs were in just for my convenience - you can ignore this bit - main issue is search is not picking any posts with ‘Richard’ in the title

Comment: Is the title exactly `Richard`? Or does it just contain Richard? Is it capitalised differently? It's unclear, there are no hard examples of data in your question to reproduce the issue or eliminate ambiguity

Comment: There are several post containing the word Richard in the test data -=. e.g. Richard Barratt, RICHARD JOnes, richard davies, RICHard, etc

The key functionality is to be able to search the titles of all child posts connected to the parent post

Comment: If you limit it to just `post_type` and `s` does it work? Do you have any plugins or `pre_get_posts` filters that are active? What are the other query vars past the `...` in your code snippet?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tom - I don't have access to this at home so will have to get back tomorrow - from recollection over the past couple of days though, there are no pre_get_post filters that are active or plugins that may cause this.

Limiting just `post_type` and `s` doesn't work. Even querying a string known to exactly match (`Forename Surname`) fails.

(A possibly interesting point) if you drop the `s` and query by a custom field value such as `candidate_email` you get a correct result ‍♂️

Comment: If you go to the job applications archive URL and add `?s=richard` on the end does that work?

Comment: Nope - sorry should have mentioned this. 

I can't seem to search within the `job_application` post_type at all - I can search without issue in the `job_listing` (parent post) post_type

Comment: I have now added the full wp_query object to the foot of the post 